# Integrate $ \int \frac{dx}{\cos^3x-\sin^3x}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

So I tried expressing all of it in terms of $\tan\frac x2$, and substitute it, but it became way too long and complicated.
I am looking for the approach which would require the least number of steps to get the final answer.

Comment: don't get excited it's a very ugly integral.

Comment: Try finding substitution as denominator $ =(\cos x- \sin x)( 1+\sin 2x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is **not simple**.

The answer is

$$
\dfrac{2\arctan\left(\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1\right)-2\arctan\left(\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1\right)+\sqrt{2}\left(\ln\left(\left|\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\sqrt{2}+1\right|\right)-\ln\left(\left|\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\sqrt{2}+1\right|\right)\right)}{3}
$$

which is certainly **not pretty**.

Hence,

1. The solution will be complicated no matter what.
2. [Online integral solvers may help you with steps.](http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=1%2F%28cosx%5E3%20-%20sinx%5E3%29)
3. Interesting insights may be provided here in the answers, but you will surely not get a short solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

Multiply numerator & denominator by $\cos x-\sin x$

As $\int(\cos x-\sin x)dx=\sin x+\cos x,$

Choose $\sin x+\cos x=u\implies2\sin x\cos x=u^2-1$

and $(\cos x-\sin x)^2=2-u^2$